# I have problem "TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined" of dispatch when using formik

Tags: javascript, redux, promise, formik

I'm trying to use formik for registration/login form and catch

> Formik.tsx:826 Warning: An unhandled error was caught from submitForm() TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Please check my code. I lost my .then from here...

loginForm.js

```
import { withFormik } from "formik";

import LoginForm from "../components/loginForm";
import store from "../../../redux/store";

import { usersActions } from "../../../redux/actions";

const LoginFormContainer = withFormik({
    enableReinitialize: true,
    mapPropsToValues: () => ({
        email: "",
        password: "",
    }),
    validate: (values) => {
        const errors = {};

        if (!values.email) {
            errors.email = "Обязательное поле";
        } else if (
            !/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i.test(values.email)
        ) {
            errors.email = "Неверный email адрес";
        }

        if (!values.password) {
            errors.password = "Введите пароль";
        }
        return errors;
    },

    handleSubmit: (values, { setSubmitting, props }) => {
        store
            .dispatch(usersActions.fetchUserLogin(values))
            .then(({data}) => {
                props.history.push('/')
            })
            .catch((e) => {console.log(e);});
    },

    displayName: "LoginForm",
})(LoginForm);

export default LoginFormContainer;
```

Here is my usersApi.js i'm using axios to post data on my back

```
import { axios } from '../../core';

export default {
    signin: (postData) => axios.post('/user/signin', postData),

}
```

and this is my redux actions

userAction.js

```
import { usersApi } from "../../helpers/api";
import { notification } from "antd";

const actions = {
    setUser: (data) => ({
        type: "USERS:SET_DATA",
        payload: data,
    }),
    setIsAuth: (bool) => ({
        type: "USER:SET_IS_AUTH",
        payload: bool,
    }),
    fetchUserLogin: (postData) => (dispatch) => {
        usersApi
            .signin(postData)
            .then(({ data }) => {
                console.log(data);
                if (data.error) {
                    const openNotificationWithIcon = (type) => {
                        notification[type]({
                            message: data.error,
                            description: data.message,
                        });
                    };
                    openNotificationWithIcon("error");
                } else {
                    const openNotificationWithIcon = (type) => {
                        notification[type]({
                            message: "Успех!",
                            description: "Добро пожаловать!",
                        });
                    };
                    openNotificationWithIcon("success");
                    window.axios.defaults.headers.common["token"] = data.token;
                    window.localStorage["token"] = data.token;
                    dispatch(actions.setUser(data));
                    dispatch(actions.setIsAuth(true));
                }
                return data;
            })
            .catch((e) => {
                const openNotificationWithIcon = (type) => {
                    notification[type]({
                        message: "Что то пошло не так",
                        description: "Попробуйте ещё раз позже",
                    });
                };
                openNotificationWithIcon("error");
                dispatch(actions.setIsAuth(false));
            });
    },

export default actions;
```

I'm looking for hours and can't find problem.

Comment: Whats the full error stack trace?

Comment: Warning: An unhandled error was caught from submitForm() TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
    at Object.handleSubmit (loginForm.js:32)
    at C._this.handleSubmit (withFormik.tsx:146)
    at Formik.tsx:851
    at Formik.tsx:1202
    at Formik.tsx:758

Comment: whats line 32 in loginForm.js?

Comment: `store.dispatch` doesn't return a `Promise` unless you have redux-thunk middleware.  Do you?